# PHPExcel: formula error (IF)

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, phpexcel

I'm trying to insert this formula

```
=IF(Datenbasis!B3<0;((Datenbasis!K3-Datenbasis!B3)/ABS(Datenbasis!B3))^(1/9)-1;(Datenbasis!$K$3/Datenbasis!$B$3)^(1/9)-1)
```

into this samplefile[1](http://www.mynettld.net/phpexceltest.zip) with this code:

```
// ....
try
{
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("phpexceltest.xls");
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("phpexceltest.xls");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $_loadingerror = TRUE;
}
if ($_loadingerror === TRUE)
{
   // Fehler beim Laden der Vorlagen-Datei!
   die("Fehler!");
}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex("0");
// ....
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("J4", "=IF(Datenbasis!B3<0;((Datenbasis!K3-Datenbasis!B3)/ABS(Datenbasis!B3))^(1/9)-1;(Datenbasis!$" . "K$3/Datenbasis!$" . "B$3)^(1/9)-1)");
// ....
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("ready.xls");
```

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Results!J4 -> undefined variable ';'' in ...\PHPExcel\Cell.php:288 Stack trace: #0 ...\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5\Worksheet.php(441): PHPExcel_Cell->getCalculatedValue() #1 ...\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5.php(171): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5_Worksheet->close() #2 phpexceltest.php(446): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('ready.xls') #3 {main} thrown in ...\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line 288
```

and I have no idea why. When I use this formula in Excel directly, it's working.

Any ideas, what to do?

Answer (score 4):

Rules for writing formulae in PHPExcel (as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-formula-into-a-cell))

- Decimal separator is '`.`' (period)
- Function argument separator is '`,`' (comma)
- Matrix row separator is '`;`' (semicolon)
- English function names must be used

unless you've explicitly set a locale for the calculation engine

---

You're using a semi-colon ('`;`') as a function argument separator

Comment: Always forget in function separator.. :D